# + Symbol is not working in PHP/SQLite database

Tags: php

I am trying to pull the user information based on the phone number. The below code is not working if the code consists of + symbol in front of the phone number but if I manually insert the number without + then it works fine.

I ran the SQL in the backend and it's pulling the information as well but + is not working in the PHP side.

**Main Code**

```
$response = array();
if(isset($_GET['phone']))
{
$phone = $_GET['phone'];

$user = $db->getUserInformation($phone);
if($user)
{
    $response["phone"] = $user["Phone"];
    $response["name"] = $user["Name"];
    $response["birthdate"] = $user["Birthdate"];
    echo json_encode($response);

}
else
{
    $response["error_msg"] = "User does not exists";
    echo  json_encode($response);
}

}
```

**User Information Code**

```
public function getUserInformation($phone)
{
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Phone=?");
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $phone);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt->close();

    return $user;
} else
    return NULL;
}
```

The code need to pull + symbol phone number as well.

**Sample Phone**

```
--->+12344567890 Not working
--->1234567890 Working
```

**Data Type Used**

```
Varchar(20)
```

Comment: More than likely the Phone field in mysql is a numeric.  Hence minuses and pluses won't work.

Comment: I am storing the phone value field as varchar(20)

Comment: Can you try echo out from **User Information Code **

Comment: What are you putting in your GET argument? `+` represents a space in a GET parameter, so you need to properly escape it using `urlencode` from the page generating the URL. You can try by manually replacing `+` with `%2B`.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is not working? What happens?

Comment: $2B didnt work as well.

Comment: @Dharman it means its going to else condition user does not exist message

Comment: Could you do `var_dump($_GET)`?

Comment: We will probably need the `getUserInformation` function code as well. Aside from that, based on what @MatsLindh mentioned, try dumping the `$phone` variable just before running the `getUserInformation` function, and see what you get when you try to run all of this with a `+` in the phone number. If you are receiving a plus sign, then the error is still unknown and we need the function code; if you receive anything else then the issue is with encoding/decoding.

Comment: @zbee The code is in the question.

Comment: My mistake, I totally skipped that. Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't the `bind_param("s", $phone)` instead be `bind_param(1, $phone)` or have `:s:` instead of `?`; Could the query not be being submitted correctly?

Comment: @zbee it looks like mysqli, so the "s" just means string, right?

Comment: Noone mentioned `$2B` - it's `%2B` and it's supposed to be in the URL requesting the page. `var_dump($_GET);` will tell you if the input is actually being submitted correctly.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You're absolutely correct.

Comment: It makes me wonder why this works at all if the database is SQLite like the question title suggests

Comment: @Don'tPanic I ignored that thinking it was a typo. user10930212, What database are you using? How do you connect to it?

Comment: If you run your query outside PHP such as CLI or GUI is the phone # properly stored?

Comment: I am using mysql database and connecting the database using PHP

Answer (score -1):

How are you data stored in the database?

If your number is stored as a numerical value, you might consider changing it to `character`.
The issue could be what is entered into the database is a number, and what you want to see aren't just number, they contain things other than numbers.

Comment: I am storing the phone value field as varchar(20)